# LD_PRELOAD socket functions java

Tags: java, linux, sockets

I have a Java programm on linux which use sockets, which receive and send packets. I writed LD_PRELOAD module which intercepts sockets functions with this java programm. I successfully use bind, connect, socket, accept functions, but i cant detect function which this java programm uses for send and receive packets, i tried functions recv, send, sendmsg, receivemsg, sendto, recvfrom, but java programm dont use them. What functions java programms use to send and receive packets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try read() or write()?  Running your software under strace is an easy way to verify what syscalls it is making.